# Get-Content Errors with Raw not parameter only when path has spaces

Tags: powershell

All the code works except when i have spaces in may path, the path have double quotes put around if a space occurs. 
Below is the code that causes the error with paths like "C:\Test Debug\Test.txt".
Error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.

```
function TurnOffDebug($path){
  try {
      $Content = (Get-Content -Path ($path) -Raw)   -replace "Debug=-1","Debug=0"
      Set-Content -path ($path) -Value $Content -NoNewline
      return $true
  }catch {
      Write-Host $_
      $dateVersion = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
      $logEntry = "$($dateVersion)- Could not set version - $($path)"
      LogWrite $logEntry
      return $false
  }

}
```

Comment: your `$Content =` line works for me. _however_, your use of `()` around your references to `$Path` seem entirely unneeded. what happens if you remove those needless parens?

Comment: also, you left out the majority of the powershell error message ... for instance, _what line of your code is producing the error_?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that is the error messae from $_ and i did mention in title and my description that get- content errors

Comment: @Lee_Dailey got that from here has a partial fix.

Comment: @user551445 - [1] i have no idea what you are referring to with `got that from here`. [2] it's **_always_** a good idea to put your _entire_ collection of info items in the Question, not scattered in the title, the body, or some other random location. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the brackets where not needed but the error still exits A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'. Here is the path with surrounding double quotes "C:\W10\Nexus\VB\NEXUS\Load Configuration File\ConfigFileIO.txt

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  They are all together you asked the questions  title: Get-Content Errors with Raw not parameter only when path has spaces
error: Error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.

Comment: @Thomas Name                                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.251 I would have tagged it with the version if i could of

Comment: How are you invoking the function, like this?  `turnoffdebug 'C:\Test Debug\test.txt'`

Comment: @js2010 yes in with variable

Comment: Try putting -raw before -path.  You might get a different error.

Answer (score -1):

Its is a bug even -LiteralPath does not work with -Raw
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6954

Work around for was any spaces in the path i took the -raw off and on the set-content remove -nonewline

```
$FilePath = 'C:\W10\New\VB\NEW\Load Configuration File\ConfigFileIO.txt'
$content =(Get-Content -LiteralPath $FilePath )  -replace "Debug=-1" , "Debug=0" 
Set-Content -path $FilePath -Value $content
```

But when I use the same code I get Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''C' does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it in ps5 with -raw, a wildcard, and the file not existing.  -raw has to be last.

Comment: @Thomas I have tried everything single quotes double quotes double quotes with single quotes inside, tried path and literal path. It works for all of the paths without spaces but those with spaces it fails, my version is PSVersion 5.1.16299.251

Comment: I don't see how this could happen unless the filename had wildcards, which includes square brackets.  `get-content file[1] -raw`.

Comment: @js2010  i have 157 paths without spaces and three with every time i pass the variable into the function i get either error. I think think that the -raw is being ignored because of the spaces. got to try and get to work without raw

Comment: What is the other error?  What are the 3 paths with spaces?

Comment: @js2010 Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''C' does not exist. when I don't use raw and pass path in single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an extra doublequote before the C?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/en-US/70dc4aa4-e883-4896-a065-d927a1e55bb9/cannot-find-drive-a-drive-with-the-name-quotc-does-not-exist?forum=winserverpowershell `$filepath = '"c:\test debug\test.txt"'`

Comment: @js2010  The there 157  paths would not work if I did

Comment: @js2010 After all the problems and solutions fix above with no signal quotes but just a string